# Different image URL than actual file path in PHP

Tags: .htaccess, url, yii, url-rewriting

I am using Yii framework. I have a product image folder in uploads/products. I want to show image src in page view source like this:

```
<img src="product1.jpg" >
```

Instead of:

```
<img src="uploads/products/product1.jpg" >
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ uploads/product/$1 [L]
```

Here we check in htaccess for the file with following extensions (jpg|jpeg|gif|png) , if the file is not exit then will check the file in uploads/product/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [.htaccess file](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files--net-4757) to make these kind of redirections.  You'll need the Apache module mod_rewrite to do this, but it's usually loaded/enabled by default.